Public_html content in wordpress C-Panel's File Manager unclickable/strange
Picture attached for the content of wp-content on how its unclickable
I have a site that I manage, it showed 'White screen of death' and so I logged into C-Panel and went to File Manager to disable the plugins, but there were two issues:

All the file names in "Public_html" folder have a strange suffix added to them: e.g "wp-content__2bfe862", so __2bfe862 is added to wp admin, wp includes and all folders.

When i click Wp-content to disable plugins, all the folders within it are unclickable for some reason?


Has anyone faced this issue before?
I have tried changing permission of the file manager but I dont think its a permission issue, as its my site.

looks like malware, try replacing WordPress core files, or restore clean backup
